# Сравнение дат.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть сегодняшняя дата:

```
var nowDate = new Date()
```

И есть некая другая дата `otherDate`.
Вопрос: *Как определить, `otherDate` это вчера, или это еще раньше (больше одного дня назад)?*
Да, и еще, как определить сегодняшнюю дату?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var now = new Date()
```

только дата:

```
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate())
```

вчерашний день:

```
var yesterday = new Date(today.valueOf() - 86400000);
```

сравнение как в вопросе:

```
var now = new Date()
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).valueOf()
var other = otherDay.valueOf()
if (other < today - 86400000) { // 24*60*60*1000
    // раньше чем вчера
} else if (other < today) {
    // вчера
} else {
    // сегодня или потом
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Красиво и удобно.

Comment: А точно там 864000000? нолик не лишний?

Answer (score 4):

Если кратко:

```
d1 = new Date('2010-10-10');
d2 = new Date('2010-10-09');
dm = d1 - d2;

if ( dm > 86400000 ) alert('Вчера--');
else alert('Позже чем вчера');
```

Вчера:

```
prev = ( new Date( ( new Date() ).toDateString() ) - 86400000 ); // 24*60*60*1000
```

Comment: И это круто! Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Определить сколько дней прошло с даты otherDate по nowDate

```
otherDate=new Date(2011,11,10);
nowDate= new Date();
delta=nowDate.getTime()-otherDate.getTime();
alert("Прошло "+Math.floor(delta/1000/60/60/24)+" дней");
```